# Computing variable importance based on decrease in performance when excluding each variable

Tags: feature-selection, random-forest

I use Random Forest for a predictive problem in which the goal is to maximize the F-measure. There are various techniques to compute variable importance in Random Forest but I'm wondering what might be wrong with this simple implementation:

Let's say we have k attributes selected after feature selection. Now we train and test k models using k-1 attributes each time and then compare the amount of decrease in performance (F-measure in my case) measure, and then rank the attributes based on that.

Any thoughts?

Comment: That's a thing that you can do.  What do you hope to learn from such a procedure?

Comment: It's a research work including a predictive model for software release planning. The model is trained on the data of multiple projects of a single company. I want to give recommendations to other researchers/practitioners who want to do a similar thing to other datasets. So I tell them these are the top candidate attributes that could be used, and potentially with this order of importance, so:

Comment: 1- researchers would know what kind of attributes to consider first and focus on more - 2- companies would know what kind of data might be worth more to record, if they were not recording so far they would, if they were, they can do it with a higher quality

Comment: That's very useful, you should include those details in your question.  Given that, I think you need to focus on the problem you are trying to solve, and whether the ranking you are proposing solves that specific problem.  We could all come up with hundreds of ways to rank variables, and call the rankings "variable importance", but what really matters is if the procedure addresses that actual question we have.