# How to do cross validation in Random Forest if the objective is to measure variable importance?

Tags: cross-validation, random-forest, randomness

As you know, the random forest algorithm and k-fold cross validation (except the case of Leave One Out) involve randomness. Thus a typical 10-fold CV in one run results in a certain variable importance values and a different run (with a different seed value, thus different splits in data) will result in different variable importance values.

Now should I go with LOO CV or maybe multiple runs of 10-fold CV and try to average variable importance values in each run to address this issue? Any other suggestions?

**P.S. 1:** I've already explained my purpose of measuring variable importance in: [Computing variable importance based on decrease in performance when excluding each variable](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/251896/71287), in the comments section.

**P.S. 2:** I understand that variable importance is algorithm dependent. But my idea here is to avoid making it seed-value dependent. I think the former is acceptable, but the latter is not.

Comment: Given that variable "importance" is such a hand-waivey measure, why are you so concerned with getting a very precise measurement of it?  Second, given that importance is calculated on the out-of-bag samples, one might say that cross-validation is implicit in the creation of the metric.

Comment: @generic_user but what if one run says X is more important than Y and another run says the other way around and this happens to most of the attributes? In terms of the way variable importance is computed, I'm using a custom approach that I've already explained in the question that I've posted a link to in the original post.

Comment: Essentially, I compute variable importance based on the extent of decrease in performance when excluding each variable.

Comment: If your answer is unstable, then I'd conclude exactly that.